# How to extend a third-party library in Python?

Tags: python, coding-style

I have a third-party Python library, that contains two classes:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a1, a2):
        self.a1=a1
        self.a2=a2

    def get_B(self):
        #many lines of code omitted, modifying self.a1 and self.a2
        return B(self.a1+self.a2)

class B:
    def __init__(self, b):
        self.b=b
    def __del__(self):
        del self.b # wipes out b at a system-level using c code. Assume it also closes a connection to some database
```

I would like to extend the functionality of class B by adding some new methods to B and by modifying some of B's methods.

For that I (presumably) would need to create a class Extended_B(B).

I would also like if A.get_B returned an instance of Extended_B, rather than B itself.

Question is:
How would I go about doing so?

My ideas:

- Overriding A.get_B by calling to super and using a copy
  constructor:

```
    class Extended_A(A):
        def get_B(self):
            old_b = super().get_B()
            new_b = Extended_B.from_old_B(old_b)
            return new_b

    class Extended_B(B):
        @classmethod
        def from_old_B(cls, old_B):
            return cls(old_B.b)
```

The problem in this case is with the **del** method: the interpreter decides to delete the old_b object as soon as the new_b is instantiated, which deletes the old_b.b object, and then new_b.b becomes None and the 
DB connection is closed.

Copying old_b.b will do no good as the DB connection will still be closed.
Moreover, sometimes it's even nontirivial to create a copy constructor(if the object underwent some transformations).

- I can, of course, just copy-paste the code of A.get_B to Extended_A and replace B with Extended_B, but that doesn't seem an elegant approach to me.
  Could you please advise on what to do best in a pythonic sense in this situation?

Comment: How about you just return `old_b` from `Extended_A(A)`, that should give you an instance of `B`: `<__main__.B at 0x2159212a518>` instead of `<__main__.Extended_B at 0x2159212a1d0>`

Comment: The main point here is that I would like get_B to return my modified Extended_B instances

Comment: I just read about reclassing in Python, so I think I might go with returning old_b and then doing old_b.__class__ = Extended_B. Though it may have some caveats, not sure

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you can solve this by keeping a reference to `old_b` so it doesn't get garbage collected:

```
class Extended_A(A):
    def get_B(self):
        old_b = super().get_B()
        self._cached_b = old_b
        new_b = Extended_B.from_old_B(old_b)
        return new_b
```

Comment: Well yes, I think I could go for it, assuming B has no __slots__ defined. Not sure what to do in this case then.

Comment: @AntonBohdanov Why would that make a difference?

Comment: Sorry, I meant "A has no __slots__". Yes, slots are not inherited, so the idea then would be to not define slots on A. Yet it's a bad practice to not inherit __slots__ AFAIK

Comment: @AntonBohdanov defining `__slots__` has purely performance implications (access time and memory).

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?:

```
In [107]: class Extended_A(A):
     ...:     def get_B(self):
     ...:         old_b = super().get_B()
     ...:         new_b = Extended_B.from_old_B(self, old_b)
     ...:         return new_b
     ...:
     ...:
     ...: class Extended_B(B):
     ...:     def from_old_B(self, old_B):
     ...:         print("Instance of {}".format(old_B))
     ...:         mod_value = old_B.b**2
     ...:         print("Modified value: {}".format(mod_value))
     ...:         return mod_value
     ...:
     ...:

In [108]: a = Extended_A(1,2)

In [109]: a.get_B()
Instance of <__main__.B object at 0x0000021591AC7080>
Modified value: 9
Out[109]: 9
```